# How do I query the SharePoint content type collection and get content types of an content type group?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I got the content type collection of SharePoint. Using the client object model, I want to query and get the content types under "List content type". What would be a LINQ query for that?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
var contentTypes = context.Web.AvailableContentTypes.Where(q => q.Group == "List content type");
```

Comment: I need it in vb.net