# Get all lists on subsites by content type with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to get all lists from subsites etc. based on their content type with REST Api. For particular list ("ProjectList") this works:

```
 /_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('ProjectList')/Items? 
 $select=ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType&$filter=ContentType eq 
 'Message'`
```

But how will I be able to retrieve ALL lists, including subpages etc. by their content type?

I have tried:

```
  /_api/Web/lists/Items? 
   $select=ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType&$filter=ContentType eq 
   'Message'`
```

Without luck.

Comment: You want to get the all Items with content Type "Message" from Root site and sub sites or you want to get all the lists where this content Type attached. if it is First then you should use Search Rest API to get the All items from Web with Content Type="Message" https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234200/rest-api-to-pull-all-list-items-that-uses-a-unique-content-type-under-a-specific

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get list then you don't have to append "items" to your rest url:

```
/_api/Web/lists?$select=ContentType/Name&$expand=ContentType&$filter=ContentType eq 'Message'
```

Comment: Thank you, but I dont get this to work. Both in my code, and in browser.

Comment: @Arte2 What error you get when you try it in browser?